# Terminate GNU Parallel in Screen Session letting jobs finish

Tags: gnu-screen, killall

I'm running a GNU Parallel command on a screen session. Unfortunately, I did not put an "&" at the end of the command to push it to the background.  Hence I do not have access to the command line on my screen session.

I would like to TERMINATE parallel so that it stops creating new jobs but finishes currently running ones.  I will need to do so outside the screen, but I don't think screen -X will work because the screen's command line isn't accepting new commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: The standard way to fix a missing `&` is:

```
CTRL-Z
bg
```

That being said, you probably want to send GNU Parallel a SIGTERM. If you only run one instance, then this should do it:

```
killall -TERM parallel
```

Comment: Thanks!  I found that Perl seemed to be responsible for parallel., so I ran `killall -TERM perl` and got a message saying "no new jobs will be started, but waiting for 5 to finish."  That sounds like the desired result.

Also, thanks for the info on CTRL-Z!  I thought Control-Z was basically the same as Control-C and didn't know "stopped" really  meant "paused."